# Передача данных в форме HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь сделать форму HTML с 2 полями (Имя и фамиллия) и кнопкой submit. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки submit страница с формой очистилась и на месте нее появились надписи: Имя - то, что ввел пользователь, Фамиллия - то, что ввел пользователь.

Форму вроде понятно как сделать. Но как через js очистить страницу и ввести введенные данные непонятно. В гугле примеров с результирующей страницей не нашел, везде только как форму делать.

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать для решения проблемы сами? Что конкретно не получилось?

Comment: Конкретно не получилось передать данные на результирующую таблицу. У меня сейчас сделана только форма. И я не понимаю: нужно создавать новый файл .htm с результирующей информацией? Как его открыть по нажатии кнопки submit? Мне бы примерчик небольшой посмотреть, и я разберусь. Просто смысл пока не очень понятен.

Comment: Ну так добавьте в вопрос ваш код (пусть и не работающий).

Comment: А нельзя на странице просто 2 контейнера поместить (2 div-а к примеру) и хайдить 1 из них в зависти от действий пользователя?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очистить страницу вы можете либо с помощью `document.write`, либо обновив содержимое некоторого контейнера с помощью свойства innerHTML 
`document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "новый текст"`;

Можно это делать и с помощью jQuery, тогда код будет чуть-чуть короче.

```js
document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = function() {
    var first_name = document.getElementById("myform_first_name");
    var last_name = document.getElementById("myform_last_name");
    document.write(first_name.value + "<br>" + last_name.value);
}
```

```html
  <div id="container">
<form id="myform">
  <label>Имя:<input name="first_name" id="myform_first_name"/></label>
  <label>Фамилия:<input name="last_name" id="myform_last_name"/></label>
  <input type=submit>
</form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!
А если результат выдавать, например, в таблице? То нужно создать новый htm файл, в нем сделать таблицу и через js передавать туда данные? И теге form написать action="result.htm"? Или можно как-то обойтись без второго файла?

Comment: Вы можете генерировать таблицу на javascript-e и показывать ее с помощью innerHTML (как я показал выше), либо с помощью document.createElement. Более продвинутые способы предполагают генерирование таблицы с помощью шаблонизатора на js, но вам к этому пока рано приступать.

Answer (score 0):

Если всё это дело будет повторяться 1 раз, то можно просто поверх влепить форму, куда будут выводиться надписи :)
А если серьезно, то проще сделать так. Создать 2ю форму такую же, только без полей (для вывода). При загрузке показывать одну, а при нажатии Submit ее прятать и показывать 2ю. А в теге form напиши action=<название функции для смены формы>. Ну а код на js думаю ты сам додумаешься как написать в документе :)

Comment: Да, это будет повторяться 1 раз. Но мне нужно в таблицу выдавать результат.

Comment: а две кнопки 1) reset 2) button к которому привязан js обработчик -- не проще ?

Comment: Ну так а что мешает на форме таблицу нарисовать?

Comment: 1) Про reset button не очень понял
2) В смысле на форме таблицу нарисовать? Тоже не очень понимаю.

Comment: Ну ты же в форме можешь html код писать. Вот и пиши таблицу там. <table><td><tr></table> и так далее...

Comment: Так если в форме нарисовать таблицу, то она сразу же будет в форме видна? Или я не понял что-то? Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на submit форма исчезала, а на месте нее появлялась результирующая таблица.

Comment: Ну я тебе и говорю. Нарисуй 2 формы. Одну показывай, другую - скрывай.